# Sending the debug message from java to flash (Electroserver 5)

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I was wondering if you could send the **getApi().getLogger().debug("message");** messages from your Java plugin to Flashbuilder? This would be very useful to debug, because if you have a nullpointer or something you could view it in your flashbuilder debug console instead of your Electroserver bat/terminal prompt. Sorry I don't hava enough reputation to add the tag "electroserver"..

Answer (score 0):

You can view the ElectroServer logs using ES Admin's Server Monitoring, Logs screen, if you don't want to look at the terminal console or the server/logs/ElectroServer5.log file.  There's a way to use JMX monitoring too but that's going to be more complicated than you want to deal with.

Another option that is available for room plugins is to implement a method that writes the message to the debug server log but also sends a plugin message to the room with the message.  Then the Flash client can just listen for those logging plugin messages and trace them.

Comment: Well I want to log the logs from the Terminal log screen into flashbuilders debug console. How would you write the method to send a room message then? Cuz I'm still learning electroserver